# Gmail API find parent of a draft

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api, email

How can I find the parent of a draft (if it exists) in Gmail?

When the user responds to a particular message in a *Gmail Thread*, the draft appears directly below it. Say for example, there was 5 messages in a thread and a draft was made in reply to the 3rd one... that draft would always appear as the 4th message. I'm attempting to reproduce this in my application, but I need a way of *mapping* a draft to the message it is in response to if any.

I've been searching through the values returned, but cannot find any reference to previous messages.

How can I do this through the API?

Edit:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the draft to the same thread, and make sure the `References` and `In-Reply-To` headers are in compliance with the `RFC 2822` standard, and that the `Subject` headers match.

**Example**

I have a thread with 3 messages. I want to create a draft that will be a response to the second one. I get the `Subject`, `Message-ID`, `References`, `In-Reply-To` headers of the message I would like to respond to, and the `threadId` of the thread:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/15a7a79ed814d9ec?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=Subject&metadataHeaders=Message-ID&metadataHeaders=References&metadataHeaders=In-Reply-To&access_token={access_token}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "15a7a79ed814d9ec",
 "threadId": "15a7a79d389926b3",
 "labelIds": [
  "UNREAD",
  "IMPORTANT",
  "SENT",
  "INBOX"
 ],
 "snippet": "Test 2 2017-02-26 13:51 GMT+01:00 Emil Tholin &lt;emtholin@gmail.com&gt;: Test 1",
 "historyId": "1138108",
 "internalDate": "1488113495000",
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "In-Reply-To",
    "value": "\u003cCADsZLRzQ8UQ1HJ8=YsvRv-jtpRY=s_wZmbL8RzSbCtw4T5A+vg@mail.gmail.com\u003e"
   },
   {
    "name": "References",
    "value": "\u003cCADsZLRzQ8UQ1HJ8=YsvRv-jtpRY=s_wZmbL8RzSbCtw4T5A+vg@mail.gmail.com\u003e"
   },
   {
    "name": "Message-ID",
    "value": "\u003cCADsZLRzHC_sR6THger6gkDjJ348XbXehQ0YsFwHAh762ht216A@mail.gmail.com\u003e"
   },
   {
    "name": "Subject",
    "value": "Re: Test"
   }
  ]
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 1333
}
```

Then I just make a draft, url-safe base64 encode it, and create it in the thread:

```
// replace '+' with '-', replace '/' with '_', remove trailing '=' to make it url-safe
var draft = btoa([
  'In-Reply-To: <CADsZLRzHC_sR6THger6gkDjJ348XbXehQ0YsFwHAh762ht216A@mail.gmail.com>\r\n',
  'References: <CADsZLRzQ8UQ1HJ8=YsvRv-jtpRY=s_wZmbL8RzSbCtw4T5A+vg@mail.gmail.com> <CADsZLRzHC_sR6THger6gkDjJ348XbXehQ0YsFwHAh762ht216A@mail.gmail.com>\r\n',
  'From: emtholin@gmail.com\r\n',
  'To: emtholin@gmail.com\r\n',
  'Subject: Re: Test\r\n'
].join('')).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/=+$/, '');
```

**Request**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts?access_token={access_token}

{
  "message": {
    "raw": "SW4tUmVwbHktVG86IDxDQURzWkxSekhDX3NSNlRIZ2VyNmdrRGpKMzQ4WGJYZWhRMFlzRndIQWg3NjJodDIxNkFAbWFpbC5nbWFpbC5jb20-DQpSZWZlcmVuY2VzOiA8Q0FEc1pMUnpROFVRMUhKOD1Zc3ZSdi1qdHBSWT1zX3dabWJMOFJ6U2JDdHc0VDVBK3ZnQG1haWwuZ21haWwuY29tPiA8Q0FEc1pMUnpIQ19zUjZUSGdlcjZna0RqSjM0OFhiWGVoUTBZc0Z3SEFoNzYyaHQyMTZBQG1haWwuZ21haWwuY29tPg0KRnJvbTogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpUbzogZW10aG9saW5AZ21haWwuY29tDQpTdWJqZWN0OiBSZTogVGVzdA0K",
    "threadId": "15a7a79d389926b3"
  }
}
```

**Result**

[image: Draft in in the middle of the thread]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the [`Users.drafts: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list) method which lists the drafts in the user's mailbox.

Sample HTTP request:
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/drafts`

If successful, it will return the `threadId` of the parent message of the draft.

```
{
 "drafts": [
  {
   "id": "s:-ID",
   "message": {
    "id": "ID",
    "threadId": "ID"
   }
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the immediate message that the draft is in response to in the context of displaying thread messages. The threadId will indicate the id of the first message in the thread but will not help for determining the position of the drafts within the thread. Say the message the draft is in response to was in position 4 out of 11 messages. I need a way to place the draft in the 5th position directly below the message it is in response to.

Comment: My current lead is to use the "Message-Id", "In-Reply-To", "References" and others to stitch the messages, back together. I previously dumped the data in html form so the values appeared not to be there.