# How to Forward email into same thread in gmail?

Tags: email, gmail-api

I am using gmail api for sending emails, I want to forward email into the same thread

As gmail has mentioned this criteria

1. The requested threadId must be specified on the Message or Draft.Message you supply with your request.
2. The References and In-Reply-To headers must be set in compliance with the RFC 2822 standard.
3. The Subject headers must match.

I have done the 1 and 3 point my question is what should we mention in

In-Reply-To and References?

And how should the api look?

Comment: Not entirely related, but [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448589/gmail-api-find-parent-of-a-draft/42469068#42469068) might help some with the headers.